# plotting 'null' and 'others' as a rectangle on rowchart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js

i have a list of 200 unique categories which i am plotting on a `dc rowchart`.

I am capping chart to 100 using `.cap(100)`

and i want to show the rest of the categories as `others` with their summation count displayed.

DC displays the count automatically as a last row on the chart but without any rectangle i.e. no width & no label and in my console i see the below error when i set `.othersGrouper(true)`

> Error:  attribute width: Expected length, "NaN".

Also, i want to plot a row where the dataset itself has string value 'null'

so it will be; 100 rows of categories + 1row for 'null' + remaining categories.

my code it tried so far;

```
this.dcBarChart = dc.rowChart(`.${divclass}`)
  .elasticX(true)
  .cap(100)
  .othersLabel('others')
  .othersGrouper(true)
  .ordinalColors(barChartColorArray)
  .measureLabelsOn(true)
  .dimension(rowChartDimension)
  .group(rowChartGroup)
  .autoScroll(true)
  .on('renderlet', (chart) => {
    ...somelogic
  });
```

Comment: just to clarify, you want your chart to have 102 rows—the top 100 rows + 1 row representing the nulls + 1 row representing the rest? dc.js uses `chart.ordering()` to pick the 100 rows, so it will be difficult to ensure that the null row appears if it's not in the top 100. Chart sort/display order is also set by `chart.ordering` at the moment, so if you use some sort of hack to ensure that the null row is displayed (e.g. by boosting it to the top when the data is ordered) it will appear that way when the graph is displayed.

Comment: [othersGrouper](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.capMixin.html#othersGrouper__anchor) takes either a function or a falsy value to suppress the others bar. You shouldn't normally need to specify it if you want to display an ordinary others bar (and I suspect you're getting a JS error from this). @ialarmedalien is right that there's currently no way to ensure that a specific bar will show in addition to the capped bars. There is probably a messy [fake group](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#fake-groups) way to do it instead of using the capping feature, not easy though.

Comment: yes, so when i have my data with value as ''null" (i.e. text string null) then the chart plots it when i dont use any capping. however when  my data is an actual null (i.e blank value) the chart doesnt club these data and plot it.

Comment: You should be looking to clean up your data before it goes into crossfilter or charting applications.

Comment: @ialarmedalien, cleaning data could be worked upon, however i am looking for anyother way to just plot null values

Comment: can you post a link to your dataset or a demo of your full code so myself and other users can have a look at ways around the problem?